# What is b in the Gompertz model?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, diffusion

I am wondering how to use the Gompertz model in modelling drug diffusion:

$$x(t) = x_\mathrm{max}\exp(-a\exp(b\log t)).$$

$x_\mathrm{max}$ is to be taken as $100,$ $a$ is the undissolved proportion at time $t = 1.$ But what is $b?$ I've seen it variously described as half of the max asymptote, the $m$ of the linear portion of the graph, or the $m$ divided by $\mathrm e.$

Comment: Your model looks different from others I've seen. I would guess that a and b are related to the max rate of change of the function during the growth phase.

Answer (score 3):

I can see at [Gompertz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_function#Formula) they use the formula below. See the link for *Graphs of Gompertz curves, showing the effect of varying one of a,b,c while keeping the others constant*

> $$f(t)=a\mathrm{e}^{-b\mathrm{e}^{-ct}}$$
> where
>
> - ''a'' is an asymptote, since $ \lim_{t \to \infty} a\mathrm{e}^{-b\mathrm{e}^{-ct }}=a\mathrm{e}^0=a$
> - ''b'' sets the displacement along the ''x''-axis (translates the graph to the left or right). When ''b'' = log(2), f(0) = a/2, also called the halfway point.
> - ''c'' sets the growth rate (''y'' scaling)
> - ''e'' is Euler's Number (''e'' = 2.71828...)
>
> The halfway point is found by solving $f(t) = a/2$ for $t$.
> $$t_{hwp} = -\frac{\ln(\ln(2)/b)}{c}$$

---

Regardless of if the equation $$x(t) = x_\mathrm{max}\exp(-a\exp(b\log t)).$$ in the question is the true one, analyzing the equation as is, being aware ift has different shape than the above.:

It can be rewritten as $$x(t)=x_\mathrm{max} \cdot  \exp{\left(-a \cdot t^b\right)}$$

If $\ce{b=1}$, the equation reduces to the classical equation of the kinetic of the first order and the half-time $t_{1/2}=\frac{\ln 2}{a}$, where an asymptote at any point in time crosses x axis after $t_{1/2}$.

$$x(t)=x_\mathrm{max} \cdot  \exp{\left(-a \cdot t \right)}$$

The parameter $\mathrm{b}$ affects the time evolution of the diffusion kinetic model..

$b = 1$ keeps the relative decrease with time constant.
$b \gt 1$ accelerates the relative decrease with time.
$b \lt 1$ decelerates the relative decrease with time.

Illustrative table about the $b$ value influence.

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}  \hline
 & b & b & b \\  \hline \hline
t & 0.8 & 1 &1.2 \\  
0 & 100 & 100 & 100 \\  
1 & 50.0 & 50.0 & 50.0 \\  
2 & 29.9 & 25.0 & 20.3 \\ 
3 & 18.8 & 12.5 & 7.5 \\  \hline
\end{array}$

$t$ was padded by small value to avoid log 0. Results were rounded.
$a$ was set to $\ln{2}$ to have $t_{1/2}=1$ for $b=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The  Gomperts rate eqn for a species population $n$ can be written as $\displaystyle \frac{dn}{dt}=-kn\ln\left(\frac{n}{a}\right)$ with initial values at time zero, $n=n_0$ and $a>0,\; k>0$. The solution is

$$  n=a e^{\ln(n_0/a)e^{-kt} }$$

At long times $t\to\infty$ the inner exponential tends to zero and so $a$ represents the limiting or maximum population $n\to a$. The rate constant $k$  limits how quickly the final population is reached.

The equation can also be written as $\displaystyle n=a(n_0/a)^{e^{-kt}}$ or $\displaystyle \ln(n/a)=\ln(n_0/a)e^{-kt}$ which may be easier to understand.